# Reading from third line of text file

Tags: java

How can I start reading from the third line of text file in Java?
I want to store 12 in 'nodes' variable, 14 in'edges' variable.
12334 in different variable and so on.
My input text file consisting of integers goes like this:

```
12
14
12334 12214 25
32151 32151 85
21514 51454 20
.
.
.
.
.

         try
                {

                    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                            array[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
                    nodes=array[0];
                    edges=array[1];
                    break;

                    for(i=2;i<5;i++)
                     {
                            array1[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(array1[i]);
                            }



                        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the current code you're using to read the file, so we can go from there?

Comment: I am able to read from the first line, after reaching the second line, I break the code,

Comment: try
     {
    
      for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                    array[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
      nodes=array[0];
      edges=array[1];
      break;

      for(i=2;i<5;i++)
       {
                    array1[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
      System.out.println(array1[i]);
                    }
      
      
                    
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: Having `break` is going to terminate the outer loop

**Suggestiones** how to solve this

**1** .  Either use `BufferReader` or `Scanner` class.

**2** . Have a counter variable set to zero

**3**. keep reading line and check if it is equal to `3` yet

**4**. continue reading line, but when the counter is equal `3`, save each line in either variable or Array

**Difference between** `BufferReader` and `Scanner`

**1**. `BufferedReader` has significantly larger buffer memory than Scanner. Use `BufferedReader` if you want to get long strings from a stream, and use `Scanner` if you want to parse specific type of token from a stream.

**2**. `Scanner` can use tokenize using custom delimiter and parse the stream into primitive types of data, while `BufferedReader` can only read and store String.

**3**. `BufferedReader` is synchronous while `Scanner` is not. Use `BufferedReader` if you're working with multiple threads.

Comment: did you get what u should do?

Comment: no i am not :(  the value in the 'nodes' and 'edges' variable is incorrect now, not 12,14.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);
int lineIndex = 0;
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if(++lineIndex > 3) {
        // do something
    }
}
```